# Array of dictionaries for String to UIColor

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, uicolor

i'm trying to make an array of dictionaries to combine a string to a UIColor . so like this all my color ( a lots of colors) will be easy to manage. i would like to call like : magenta and then , under the hood , to have the UIColor in RGB

i have tried this but it throws an error:

```
let gColor: [String]:[UIColor] = 
        ["magenta"]:[UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)]
        // and like 100 colors are stored here , but isn't working when i call them
```

Comment: You need to use ordinary dictionary 'var gColor: [String: UIColor]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is

```
var gColor: [String : UIColor] = ["magenta":UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)]
```

Alternatively define a struct outside any class

```
struct Color {
 static let Black = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
 static let Red = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
}
```

and call a color with

```
let color = Color.Red
```

Comment: And how do I use it : 
var topColor: UIColor = **colors.magenta**
var topColor: UIColor = **colors[magenta]**
var topColor: UIColor = **colors(magenta)**
I know its a stupid question but i'm kinda new and i dont know all the 
syntax.
@vadian

Comment: The syntax declaring `gColor` : `var topColor = gColor["magenta"]` , the type annotation is not needed, the compiler infers the type. The syntax to call s struct member is described in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let gColor: [String:UIColor] = ["magenta": UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)]
```

If you need change dictionary dynamically, use this code:

```
var gColor = [String:UIColor]()
gColor["magenta"] = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
```